Storing Python plots in variables for later use (like it is possible in R)
I'm writing code to perform exploratory dataset analysis and as part of this I would like to plot some of the variables in the dataset. I would like to have a function to generate the plot objects that then can be called upon and displayed as needed in the Jupyter Notebook. In R I can something like this:
# install.packages("tidyverse")
# install.packages("ggpubr")
supress_all <- function(e) {suppressPackageStartupMessages(suppressWarnings(e))}
supress_all(library(tidyverse))
supress_all(library(ggpubr))

# Adjust size of the plots in jupyter
options(repr.plot.width = 10, repr.plot.height = 4)

make_me_a_plot <- function(data, x_name, y_name) {
    
    res <- ggplot() +
        geom_point(aes(x = data[[x_name]], y = data[[y_name]])) +
        labs(title = paste0(x_name, " vs ", y_name), x = x_name, y = y_name)
    
    return(res)
}

p1 <- make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "hp")
p2 <- make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "wt")
p3 <- make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "qsec")

Then when I want to call my plots I can do something like this.
# Plot just 2 plots and ignore the last one generated - p3
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

This will look something like this in Jupyter.

Plots p1, p2, p3 are still available and can be used multiple times or modified on the fly. How do I achieve the same thing in Python? Example code that is NOT working below.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
plt.ioff()

mtcars = sns.load_dataset('mpg')

x_name = 'mpg'
y_name = 'horsepower'

def make_me_a_plot(data, x_name, y_name):
    res = plt.scatter(x=data[[x_name]], y=data[[y_name]])
    return res

p1 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, 'mpg', 'horsepower')
p2 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, 'mpg', 'weight')
p2 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, 'mpg', 'acceleration')

# What next? plt.show() will just draw all of the plots on the same figure.

Calling plt.show() will just show ALL plots. Not what is desired.


EDIT: Suggested solution from Plygon using patchworklib.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import patchworklib as pw

plt.ioff()
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
mtcars = sns.load_dataset("mpg")

x_name = "mpg"
y_name = "horsepower"


def make_me_a_plot(
    data: pd.DataFrame,
    x_name: str,
    y_name: str,
) -> pw.Brick:
    ax = pw.Brick(figsize=(6, 4))
    sns.scatterplot(
        x=x_name,
        y=y_name,
        data=data,
        ax=ax,
        s=4**2,
    )
    ax.set_title(f"{x_name} vs. {y_name}")
    return ax


p1 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "horsepower")
p2 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "weight")
p3 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "acceleration")

Then if I would like to display the figure I just need to call
p1.savefig()
# Or directly
make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "horsepower").savefig()

This however does not work right in my environment when trying to combine figures.
# Combine more than 1 figure
p1 | p2


This yields result that is not readable in the dark environment.

You can use plotnine to get ggplot functionality and syntax in python and patchworklib to replace ggpubr for ggarrange (not 1:1).
With plotnine:
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_point, labs

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import patchworklib as pw

plt.ioff()

mtcars = sns.load_dataset("mpg")

x_name = "mpg"
y_name = "horsepower"


def make_me_a_plot(data: pd.DataFrame, x_name: str, y_name: str) -> pw.Brick:
    res = (
        ggplot(data)
        + geom_point(aes(x=x_name, y=y_name))
        + labs(title=f"{x_name} vs {y_name}", x=x_name, y=y_name)
    )
    return pw.load_ggplot(res)


p1 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "horsepower")
p2 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "weight")
p3 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "acceleration")


p1 | p2


With matplotlib/seaborn:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import patchworklib as pw

plt.ioff()
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
mtcars = sns.load_dataset("mpg")

x_name = "mpg"
y_name = "horsepower"


def make_me_a_plot(
    data: pd.DataFrame,
    x_name: str,
    y_name: str,
) -> pw.Brick:
    ax = pw.Brick(figsize=(6, 4))
    sns.scatterplot(
        x=x_name,
        y=y_name,
        data=data,
        ax=ax,
        s=4**2,
    )
    ax.set_title(f"{x_name} vs. {y_name}")
    return ax


p1 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "horsepower")
p2 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "weight")
p3 = make_me_a_plot(mtcars, "mpg", "acceleration")

p1 | p2


You can use | to put plots next to eachother (row-wise) and / below eachother (column-wise).
Note: patchworklib, more specifically load_ggplot, does not work with the latest version of plotnine. Install plotnine==0.12.4.

Thanks for this recommendation. I was more after being able to pass around my plots as variables rather than displaying them straight away. patchworklib achieves this by enabling me to call savefig() method of the pw.Brick object.
On a side note, I do experience some weird issues with this when running in vs code, but it could be something to do with my set up.

Yes, I think that there is an issue with the patchworklib.Bricks image representation in VS Code or Jupyter notebooks in general. You can also call savefig on the combination of two subplots, e.g., (p1 | p2).savefig() and it should display as above.
